# I'm using PropertyChanged to update textblock, but when clicked, crashed: Application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: c++, winui-3, c++-winrt

Now I'm trying to use PropertyChangedEvent to test update the textblock, but when I click, it crashed: WinRT originate error - 0x8001010E : The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.

```
//in WordArray.cpp

namespace winrt::Lexical_Frequency::implementation
{
    WordArray::WordArray(winrt::hstring const& allword) : m_allword{ allword }
    {
    }

    winrt::hstring WordArray::AllWord()
    { 
        return m_allword;
    }

    void WordArray::AllWord(winrt::hstring const& value)
    {
        if (m_allword != value)
        {
            m_allword = value;
            m_propertyChanged(*this, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"AllWord" });
        }
    }
    
    winrt::event_token WordArray::PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler)
    {
        return m_propertyChanged.add(handler);
    }

    void WordArray::PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token)
    {
        m_propertyChanged.remove(token);
    }
}
```

```
//in DataPage.xaml.cpp
namespace winrt::Lexical_Frequency::implementation
{
    DataPage::DataPage()
    {
        m_mainviewModel = winrt::make<Lexical_Frequency::implementation::WordArrayViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void DataPage::ClickHandler(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
    {
        MainViewModel().WordArray().AllWord(L"xxx");
    }

    void DataPage::SaveFileButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
    {
        GetFileNameSave();
    }

    Lexical_Frequency::WordArrayViewModel DataPage::MainViewModel()
    {
        return m_mainviewModel;
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to use MainViewModel().WordArray().AllWord(L"To Kill a Mockingbird"); to test update the textblock, but when I click, it crashed: WinRT originate error - 0x8001010E : The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll frequently encounter this error when dropping code written for Microsoft's "Modern" UI platform (that never got a name) into a WinUI 3 application.

A bit of historic context: Alongside the "Modern" UI platform, Windows 8 introduced a variation of the STA, the Application STA (wildly [undocumented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidlbase/ne-objidlbase-apttypequalifier)<sup>1</sup>, no surprises there). Windows 10 finally exposed the "Modern" UI platform (still unnamed) through Windows Runtime types under the `Windows.UI.Xaml` namespace. (Most) of those types will want to be accessed from the ASTA (which is apparently enforced at run time, evidenced by the `RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD` "exception").

Fast forward to today, the "Modern" UI platform mostly gone, together with its clean design language. The UWP sharing a coffin with Windows 10 Mobile, and the ASTA history, too. WinUI 3 has come full circle, ultimately supporting the classic Desktop application model only, back to the classic [COM threading architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/processes--threads--and-apartments#the-apartment-and-the-com-threading-architecture): Zero or one MTA, and any number of STAs.

No ASTA, anywhere.

After that bit of a detour it should be easy to understand, what the issue is: The code is trying to access objects designed for the ASTA from a regular STA thread.

The solution is pretty straight forward, too: Replace all types from the `Windows.UI.Xaml` namespace with their WinUI 3 twins from the `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` namespace:

- In the IDL for `WordArray` make sure to derive from [`Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged) rather than [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged)
- Change the type parameter for the `winrt::event` class template from [`Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.propertychangedeventhandler) to [`Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.data.propertychangedeventhandler) and update the `PropertyChanged` implementations to use this type as well
- Construct a [`Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.data.propertychangedeventargs) object instead of a [`Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.propertychangedeventargs) object when raising events

To do this you will also have to update the respective `#include` directives that reference `<winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml. ... .h>` header files to use `<winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml. ... .h>` instead, and replace any `using namespace` directives accordingly.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Raymond Chen explains what problem it is trying to solve in his blog entry [What is so special about the Application STA?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210224-00/?p=104901).*

Comment: Thank you so much! Professional. It works well! I’m a starter of WinUI, too much need to learn.